# Create Func<Type> from TypeInfo and MethodInfo

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

I'm curious whether it's possible to create a delegate while having only the type at hand.
Something like this:

```
var concreteType = DiscoverTypeInRuntime();
var methodName = "SomeNameIKnowInAdvance";
var methodInfo = concreteType.GetMethodInfo(methodName);
var dynamicallyConstructedFunc = DynamicallyConstructFunc(methodInfo)
```

The delegate should be of type

```
Func<ConcreteType>
```

UPDATED:

The exact type is not known in advance. It is discovered during the program run time. The delegate can't be of type `Func<object` only the `Func<ConcreteType>` is allowed.
The method whose name is known is the factory method which returns an instance of `ConcreteType` thus the requirement.

UPDATED 2:

I will provide here some code to explain the use case. Hope this will clarify the question:

```
public class LoginProviderBuilder : FakeBuilderBase<ILoginProvider>
{        
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _users = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    private LoginProviderBuilder()
    {

    }
    //...
}

public class Module : ProvidersModuleBase
{
    protected override void OnRegisterProviders(IIocContainerRegistrator iocContainer)
    {
        base.OnRegisterProviders(iocContainer);
        RegisterAllBuilders(iocContainer, LoginProviderBuilder.CreateBuilder);
        RegisterAllBuilders(iocContainer, WarehouseProviderBuilder.CreateBuilder);
        RegisterAllBuilders(iocContainer, EventsProviderBuilder.CreateBuilder);
    }
}

protected void RegisterAllBuilders<TProvider>(IIocContainerRegistrator iocContainerRegistrator, 
        Func<FakeBuilderBase<TProvider>> defaultBuilderCreationFunc) where TProvider : class
    {
        var builders = BuildersCollectionContext.GetBuilders<TProvider>().ToArray();
        if (builders.Length == 0)
        {
            RegistrationHelper.RegisterBuilder(iocContainerRegistrator, defaultBuilderCreationFunc());
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var builder in builders)
            {
                RegistrationHelper.RegisterBuilder(iocContainerRegistrator, builder);
            }
        }
    }
```

In short the task in hand is to discover all eligible builder type dynamically and register them automagically while somehow preserving the concrete type and the existing generics API.

If this code is not clear you can find the sample solution here:
https://github.com/LogoFX/Samples.Specifications

Comment: I've given an answer, but necessarily the compile-time type will just be `Delegate`. If that doesn't do everything you need, please clarify your question to explain what you'd expect to *do* with the delegate after creating it.

Comment: Updated the question @JonSkeet

Comment: It's really not clear to me how the code in your update relates to the rest of the question.

Comment: RegisterAllBuilders(iocContainer, LoginProviderBuilder.CreateBuilder);
        RegisterAllBuilders(iocContainer, WarehouseProviderBuilder.CreateBuilder);
        RegisterAllBuilders(iocContainer, EventsProviderBuilder.CreateBuilder); This code should be replaced with RegisterAllBuilders(iocContainer, allFactoryBuilderMethods) where allFactorybuilderMethods should be constructed dynamically using the code I'm looking for.

Comment: So you need to call a generic method as well? That wasn't mentioned at all before... but there are other questions around calling a generic method with reflection. Put that together with my answer and it should be fine.

Comment: I will try your suggestion though it feels like something's missing here.

Comment: Well what do you think is missing? You construct the delegate, you pass it to the `RegisterAllBuilders` method...

Comment: RegisterAllBuilders expects certain signature of `Func<FakeBuilderBase<TProvider>>` not `Delegate`. So I need to change it signature as well.

Comment: Well not if you follow my suggestion of calling it via reflection... (It's not really clear to me what `FakeBuilderBase` is meant to be, nor what `BuildersCollectionContext` does, but there we go...)

Answer (score 3):

With the help of some *Reflection* you can construct a function that does that like this:

```
private Func<T> GetDelegateFromMethodName<T>(string methodName)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var method = type.GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == methodName);
    if (method == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(methodName));
    }
    return (Func<T>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T>), method);
}
```

Here is an example usage:

```
var methodName = "SomeNameIKnowInAdvance";
var dynamicallyConstructedFunc = GetDelegateFromMethodName<ConcreteClass>(methodName);
```

Keep in mind this will only work for static methods, if you want to make it work for instance methods too you need to pass an instance as well:

```
private Func<T> GetDelegateFromMethodName<T>(T instance, string methodName)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var method = type.GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == methodName);
    if (method == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(methodName));
    }
    return (Func<T>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T>), instance, method);
}
```

An example usage of that would be:

```
var methodName = "ConstructClass";
var dynamicallyConstructedFunc = GetDelegateFromMethodName<ConcreteClass>(new ConcreteClass(), methodName);
```

If you don't like generics you can use `object` too but that wont result in `Func<ConcreteClass>` you will have to cast it manually:

```
private Func<object> GetDelegateFromMethodName(object instance, string methodName)
{
    var type = instance.GetType();
    var method = type.GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == methodName);
    if (method == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(methodName));
    }
    return (Func<object>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object>), instance, method);
}

private Func<object> GetDelegateFromMethodName(Type type, string methodName)
{
    var method = type.GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == methodName);
    if (method == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(methodName));
    }
    return (Func<object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object>), method);
}
```

Comment: Is there a non-generic version for this?
I don't know the T in compile-time. It gets discovered dynamically by naming convention match.

Comment: I updated the answer, would that do the job @GenaVerdel ?

Comment: `ArgumentNullException` may not be the best choice of exception type to throw. I would go with a plain old `ArgumentException`. `ArgumentNullException` suggests that the argument its self is `null`, while `ArgumentException` suggests that the value of the argument is incorrect.  The former should only ever be thrown when the argument passed to the method is `null`.

Comment: Good point @BradleyUffner. Will update the answer to reflect that suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Still not exactly what I'm looking for. Maybe this is impossible in C#. I'll update the question to explain the case better.

Comment: CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object>) is not working for me. It says "Cannot bind to the target method because its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type". I have "Int32 ReadInt()" method.

Answer (score 1):

You can create such a delegate - but you'll only be able to refer to it as a `Delegate` because you don't know the actual type at compile-time. It requires creating the appropriate delegate type from `Func<T>` using [`MakeGenericType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype).

```
var concreteType = DiscoverTypeInRuntime();
var methodName = "SomeNameIKnowInAdvance";
var methodInfo = concreteType.GetMethodInfo(methodName);
var funcType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(concreteType);
var func = Delegate.CreateDelegate(funcType, methodInfo)
```

That will create the right kind of delegate, referring to the right method... but the compile-time type will still just be `Delegate`.

Comment: I assume he is later operating on the functor as it were from some type, i.e accessing it's members, but that still doesn't makes much sense because in this case the type should be know during the compile-time. Besides that maybe a `dynamic` solution would suit OP needs better, what are your thoughts on that?

Comment: @Deadzone: Without knowing more about the OP's real needs, I'd rather not speculate.

Comment: Another limitation I forgot to mention: this code should be portable (for now)

Comment: @GenaVerdel: What *exactly* do you mean by "portable"? This should work fine targeting .NET Standard, for example.

Comment: portable as in PCL Profile 111. The library has not been ".NET Standardized" yet

Comment: @GenaVerdel: Okay, so is that causing any problems? I can't remember exactly what's in that profile, but all of the code I'm calling here is pretty basic.

Comment: Delegate.CreateDelegate is not available for this profile

Comment: @GenaVerdel: Without `Delegate.CreateDelegate` you're really pretty stuck. It doesn't help that you didn't mention this PCL profile 111 requirement (which is *really* restrictive) for nearly 4 days...

Comment: Thanks for your time @Jon Skeet. I'm gonna switch to non-generic version for now.